# is there any different ways testing update process of database , except **affected_rows()**, in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

i need some help about testing update process. i know there is **affected_rows()** function to show succesful update. but when columns values same as previous columns, i want to return TRUE  or show succes message by some prepared codeigniter or mysqli function.(if there is)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return true even the column values are same, return true always in the model function, so you don't have to use affected_rows() in your case.

Comment: allright, i will try. i just wonder if there is a prepared function for this job, like affected_rows(). thanks.

Comment: In your case you don't need, as I understood your question, you won't get affected_rows() if the column values are same, that means no update has been occurs, but you need to show update successfully message to user. so you don't have to use any function rather than returning true, or just show the massage in each update action